# Custom classes in bootstrap - Styling Design pattern

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a Styling design pattern question regarding .less and .css files.

I'm using bootstrap to develop my web page. Lets say I have a nav-bar in the page. The nav-bar has a h1 for some title and , uses ul for menu. The h1 and ul has custom styling.

I can do it two ways, right.

I can create a class called .pagetitle and .main-menu and define styles accordingly.

```
// mystyle.less
.pagetitle { 
        font-size : 36px
}
.main-menu { 
   ....
}   

// mypage.html
<div class="nav navbar"> 
<h1 class="pagetitle"> BIG TITLE </h1> 
...
<ul class="main-menu">
...
</ul> 
</div>
```

or, I change the default behaviour of elements and classes based on where they are placed.

```
// mystyle.less
.navbar { 
    .h1, h1 {
        font-size : 36px
    }
    ul { 
        ....
    }   
}

// mypage.html
<div class="nav navbar"> 
<h1> BIG TITLE </h1> 
    ...
<ul>
    ...
</ul> 
</div>
```

Which approach is better and why?

Comment: both are fine unless and untill you dont have redundant css rules. like having two different classes with same set of rules is not desired its just extra pain for browser to render. always try using existing classes if you can. file size matter. hence css files are always minimized for production.

I have not used less but i have used scss. where scss is better thn css if you know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a class for the h1. All that does is bloat your html with unnecessary code. Also it looks like in your second example you called the h1 one as a class and you don't/shouldn't do that.  I would do it like this.

```
.navbar h1 { 
   font-size: 36px;
}

.navbar ul {
    float: left;
}
```

Hope this helps!